# Parsing text file read from URL fails

Tags: r, parsing

This should be an easy one--I run periodic reports in `Knitr` where I fetch live data for further processing. One of my lines has ceased to function, though, for reasons not clear to me; hence this question.

```
fed_data<-getURL('http://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/Output.aspx?rel=H15&series=4c9742f6cd2efded850db98de3f2c75d&lastObs=&from=&to=&filetype=csv&label=include&layout=seriescolumn')
```

This is unproblematic. The issue is with parsing the resulting string (here the start of the returned string is shown)

> substr(fed_data,1,400)
>       [1] "\"Series Description\",\"CONTRACT RATE ON 30-YEAR, FIXED-RATE CONVENTIONAL HOME MORTGAGE COMMITMENTS\"\r\n\"Unit:\",\"Percent\"\r\n\"Multiplier:\",\"1\"\r\n\"Currency:\",\"NA\"\r\n\"Unique Identifier: \",\"H15/H15/RMMPCCFC_N.M\"\r\n\"Time Period\",\"RMMPCCFC_N.M\"\r\n1971-04,7.31\r\n1971-05,7.43\r\n1971-06,7.53\r\n1971-07,7.60\r\n1971-08,7.70\r\n1971-09,7.69\r\n1971-10,7.63\r\n1971-11,7.55\r\n1971-12,7.48\r\n1972-01,7.44\r\n1972-02,7.33\r\n1972-03,7.30\r\n"

Then I try to parse, skipping the first six lines (assuming carriage returns are properly recognized):

```
interest <- scan(fed_data,skip=6, allowEscapes = T, quote="\"", sep=",")
```

Resulting output:

```
> interest <- scan(fed_data,skip=6, allowEscapes = T,quote="\"", sep=",")
Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "r") :
  cannot open file '"Series Description","CONTRACT RATE ON 30-YEAR, FIXED-RATE CONVENTIONAL HOME MORTGAGE COMMITMENTS"
"Unit:","Percent"
"Multiplier:","1"
"Currency:","NA"
"Unique Identifier: ","H15/H15/RMMPCCFC_N.M"
"Time Period","RMMPCCFC_N.M"
1971-04,7.31
1971-05,7.43
1971-06,7.53
```

Any ideas as to why this is not parsed properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use?

```
url='http://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/Output.aspx?rel=H15&series=4c9742f6cd2efded850db98de3f2c75d&lastObs=&from=&to=&filetype=csv&label=include&layout=seriescolumn'
df <- read.csv(url,skip=5)
head(df)
#   Time.Period RMMPCCFC_N.M
# 1     1971-04         7.31
# 2     1971-05         7.43
# 3     1971-06         7.53
# 4     1971-07         7.60
# 5     1971-08         7.70
# 6     1971-09         7.69
```

The problem with `scan(...)` is that the first argument is being interpreted as a file name. You can fix this with

```
scan(textConnection(fed_data),...)
```

but it's still not parsing correctly. `read.csv(...)` was built for this.

You can also do this even more simply using

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("MORTG",src="FRED")
head(MORTG)
#            MORTG
# 1971-04-01  7.31
# 1971-05-01  7.43
# 1971-06-01  7.53
# 1971-07-01  7.60
# 1971-08-01  7.70
# 1971-09-01  7.69
```

Answer (score 1):

The `scan` help file says (above the examples) that `read.table` is a more "user-friendly" way to read data matrices (and `readLines` for multiple files).  This can be done by

```
> url <- 'http://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/Output.aspx?rel=H15&series=4c9742f6cd2efded850db98de3f2c75d&lastObs=&from=&to=&filetype=csv&label=include&layout=seriescolumn'
> f <- read.table(url, skip = 6, sep = ",")
> head(f)
       V1   V2
1 1971-04 7.31
2 1971-05 7.43
3 1971-06 7.53
4 1971-07 7.60
5 1971-08 7.70
6 1971-09 7.69
```

To get the column headers, adjust `skip` and add `header = TRUE`

```
read.table(url, skip = 5, sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```